# New Mac Mini 5,1 wireless & Bluetooth not working

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, mac, mac-mini

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
Macmini5,1
```

I have the newest available Mac Mini at time of this writing.

Installation of Ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10 goes ok only bluetooth and wireless is not working.

**Bluetooth**

Currently I'm running 11.04 as according to: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Macmini4-1/Maverick#Wireless
To get bluetooth working I need to install btusb-dkms which is not available from ppa in 11.10 yet.

This have not gotten my bluetooth to function however.

**Wireless**

As the new Mac Mini is based on i5 and sandy bridge and not the old Intel core 2 duo tech, I tried following some of the new Macbook Air guides without luck as well.

The Wireless is not displayed at network-manager and unfortunately I do not know how to figure out what driver I need for that, so if anyone can be helpful with that I will gladly post any output of any commands here.

My main concern is the wireless, as for some reason the bluetooth keyboard and mouse works without OS interference for now probably because it was linked from OS X before ubuntu was installed.

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

**Update nov 7th:**

Kernel 3.1 supports bluetooth out of the box. The wireless broadcom b43 is still not working.

There are different hacks to the kernel to get wireless working but I have not had any success with any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you would need to wait for correct hardware functionality for the Sandy Bridge and other devices in the Kernel. Right now this is being worked on and am sure for the 3.1 kernel version many fixes will be made regarding this. So for now give it some time for the work for this hardware to get to the kernel. If a PPA that addresses this for Ubuntu appears it would need to be compatible with the version you are using.

Also for what I have seen, 3.0 version of the Kernel and 3.1 version have a lot of work for the Sandy Bridge hardware: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_snb_linux31&num=1

For the remark about "mac hardware only works on mac" not true. It has been mentioned, showed, tested and confirmed that linux works in anything that uses any of the architecture it supports. I have seen several Macs that use Ubuntu so you can imagine my face with something like this. Basically, if it uses electricity that hardware can have linux.

There are even official pages about it:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromMacOSX

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook

Comment: Thankyou, and yes I am using 12,1 Imac's in production running ubuntu 11.04 without any issues. From further reading I can see bluetooth 4 is used in new mac mini which probably is not supported yet either.

Comment: @Axlrod - Do not worry, at the speed every hardware is added, you will not have to wait a lot. Visit kernelnewbies site to see changes for the 3.1 kernel and new stuff.

Comment: bluetooth is working in kernel 3.1, now only wireless for b43 is missing. This has been promised to arrive in 3.2